# How to remove git older commits and keep latest commit only?

Tags: git

I have this requirement to drop all older commits and push recent commits only. so I am trying to remove the older commit which is g7688bc3... and keep 0455a4f67 this latest commit only on my branch.   I've tried hard reset, but still, an older commit exists, and rebase editor shows none of the commits to dropping. Any suggestion?.

```
commit 0455a4f6741942ea3a4526957dbb62c4cc144458f2
Author: adminuser <admin@email.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 1 11:55:39 2021 +0830

    Create test branch

commit g7688bc3dhhd1a3642fg76b885b1ac87dc98658b27
Author: rootuser <admin@email.com>
Date:   Mon Nov 15 14:01:22 2020 +0830

    Create main branch
```

Comment: Do you really want to _drop_ the older commits, thus undoing them? Or incorporate all the commits into a single commit, thus combining them?

Comment: Hi matt, I really want to drop the older commits. that's the requirement. I don't want to incorporate all the commits. Thank you

Comment: @bsd How did you use `rebase`? Where the commits are in the history?

Comment: I tried to rebase options as well. I was also trying different options. None of them are worked to drop the older commits from the local branch

Comment: Google for "git rebase interactive", you will find indications on how to use `git rebase -i`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to go around it is to create an orphan branch, then it will have no history... and your commit will be the first one:

```
git checkout --orphan new-branch
git commit -m "first commit on new branch"
```

Then you could put the old branch over here:

```
git branch -f old-branch
git checkout old-branch
```

But you are losing all the previous history so use with care.